# Importing CSV into Sheets takes too long

Tags: csv, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to import a CSV of approx. 7500 lines from a GMail attachment into Google Sheets and it is taking longer than the allowed 6 minutes to execute.

I am following this tutorial: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/docslist_tutorial#section2 and my code is listed below

The section consuming all the time is the pushing of data into the new sheet:

```
  // Push data into the sheet
  for ( var n=0, lenCsv=csvData.length; n<lenCsv; n++ ) {
    newsheet.getRange(n+1, 1, 1, csvData[n].length).setValues(new Array(csvData[n]));
  }
```

**Is there any way I can improve the performance of this and make it faster?**

Thanks in advance.

My code is listed below.

```
      var attachmentData = attachments[k].getDataAsString();


      var attachmentClean = attachmentData.split('  ').join(',');
      var attachmentCleanA = attachmentClean.split(',');

      var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(attachmentCleanA);

      var SheetName = String(csvData[1]).substring(5,7)+ "-" + String(csvData[1]).substring(0,4);

      Logger.log("SheetName:"+SheetName);

      ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('XXXXXXXXX');

      var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(SheetName);

      if (sheet == null){
        var newsheet = ss.insertSheet(SheetName);
      }else{
        sheet.clearContents();
        var newsheet = sheet;
      }
      Logger.log("Entering "+csvData.length+" rows");

      // Push data into the sheet
      for ( var n=0, lenCsv=csvData.length; n<lenCsv; n++ ) {
        newsheet.getRange(n+1, 1, 1, csvData[n].length).setValues(new Array(csvData[n]));
      }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(attachmentCleanA);
```

Creates a two dimensional array.  [Google Documentation - parseCsv](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#parseCsv(String))

If your `csvData` variable truly is a 2D array, then all you need to do is use this line of code without the `for` loop:

```
newsheet.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
```

The range starts in row one, column one, and sets a range that is the length of the outer array of the csvData, and the number of columns to the number of elements in the first inner array.

Note that if your data has inner arrays of different lengths, `setValues()` will produce an error.

If all of your inner arrays are *not* the same length, then you can *not* avoid looping through every inner array.  But, I don't know what your data looks like.  If each line of data in your CSV has the same number of vales in the row, then you don't need the `for` loop.

So, improving the part of the code that is taking all the time, is totally dependent upon whether the rows are all the same length or not.

You shouldn't need the `new Array()` part in the `setValues()` method.  If the `csvData` array truly is a good 2D array, then it's already an array.  You don't need to create another array from something that's already an array.

Comment: Thanks Sandy, that did work and was MUCH quicker.. I will keep your comment about complete data in mind though. Thanks

Comment: Hard to believe that tutorial still has that inefficient code!